# How to login with kotak securities trade api?

Tags: python

I am writing a trading algo code with kotak securities trade api

I am getting this error on login:

```
E:\PROJECTS\Kotak>python kotak.py
Exception  (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response body: {"fault":{"code":900901,"message":"Invalid Credentials","description":"Access failure for API: /apim/session/1.0, version: 1.0 status: (900901) - Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials"}}
```

This is my code:

```
import json
from ks_api_client import ks_api
 
credentials_file = open("credentials.json","r")
credentials = json.load(credentials_file) 
credentials_file.close()

try:
    client = ks_api.KSTradeApi(access_token = credentials["accessToken"], userid = credentials["userID"],consumer_key = credentials["consumerKey"], ip = "", app_id = credentials["appID"], host="https://tradeapi.kotaksecurities.com/apim")
    client.login(password = credentials["password"])
    client.session_2fa(access_code = "6032")

except Exception as e:
        print("Exception  %s\n" % e)
```

I entering login username instead of client id and use the production keys of kotak...

Comment: I suggest you review the documentation for ks_api_client and also ensure that the data acquired from credentials.json is what you expected

Comment: I have given the right credentials in json file... The exception is raised while initialising the client... That is first line in try block... Kindly try to help with the code

Comment: I note that the source code for ks_api_client is available on Github. Have you reviewed the source code? You may find that enlightening

Comment: I had viewed it already and not seemed to help me out... Documentation is poor

Comment: Where do I find the access token, every time I click on create account it takes me to demat account creations page. Does that mean we need to open a demat account to access api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also getting the same error and following parameters worked for me:
access_token = "generate and update new access token of production keys", userid = "userlogin id which is same as application owner", consumer_key="consumer key of production keys", ip = "127.0.0.1", app_id = "name of application e.g. DefaultApplication", host = "https://ctradeapi.kotaksecurities.com/apim".
If you are creating a new application then select "Reference (Opaque)" as token type.

Comment: Generating a fresh access token makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting this app_id from ? I dont see this mentioned anywhere within the Kotak API login thats why I am asking. I see only Default App, Consumer Key, Consumer Secret and Access Token under the OAuth2 Tokens section.

app_id = credentials["appID"]

Comment: appID is empty variable ""

Comment: Ok - glad to know its working fine for you now.